# React-virtualized. Calling public methods of List element has no effect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-virtualized

I am trying to use  from React-virtualized.

In the following component I am trying to call  public methods. The problem is, these methods are called (I see them called while debugging, but they have no visible effect.

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import {List, AutoSizer, CellMeasurer, CellMeasurerCache} from "react-virtualized";

class InfiniteScroller extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.cache = new CellMeasurerCache({
            fixedWidth: true,
            defaultHeight: 50
        });
        this.state = {
            currentLineSt: 50,
            currentLineEnd: 100,
        }
    }

    renderRow = ({index, parent, key, style}) => {
        let className = "code-line";
        if (this.state.currentLineSt <= index && this.state.currentLineEnd >= index) {
            className += " code-line-focus";
        }

        return (
            <CellMeasurer
                key={key}
                cache={this.cache}
                parent={parent}
                columnIndex={0}
                rowIndex={index}
            >
                <div style={style} className={className}>
                    <span className={"code-index"}><b>{index}: </b></span>
                    <span className={"code"} style={{whiteSpace: "pre-wrap"}}>{this.props.data[index]}</span>
                </div>
            </CellMeasurer>
        )
    };

componentDidUpdate() {
    // these methods are called but do nothing visible
    this.myInfiniteList.forceUpdateGrid();
    this.myInfiniteList.scrollToRow(100);
}

componentDidMount() {
    // these methods are called but do nothing visible
    this.myInfiniteList.forceUpdateGrid();
    this.myInfiniteList.scrollToRow(100);
}

    render() {
        return (
            <AutoSizer>
                {
                    ({width, height}) => {
                        return <List
                            ref={(ref) => this.myInfiniteList = ref}
                            forceUpdateGrid
                            rowCount={this.props.data.length}
                            width={width}
                            height={height}
                            deferredMeasurementCache={this.cache}
                            rowHeight={this.cache.rowHeight}
                            rowRenderer={this.renderRow}
                        />
                    }
                }
            </AutoSizer>
        );
    }
}

export default InfiniteScroller;
```

I need to call them since: 
1) After data change, line size does not change
2) Need a way to scroll to line on click.

Any ideas why it doesn't work or how I could do this differently would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Post your code as a Codesandbox (or similar) that can be run. It's helpful.

Comment: Here it is https://codesandbox.io/s/lp198kyl79

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to talk more Brian to get a real understanding, but it appears your list isn't fully initialized on componentDidMount.

Note in this sandbox (took yours and tweaked): https://codesandbox.io/s/lro6358jr9

The log of the element in componentDidMount has an array of 0 for children, whereas the log when I click to do the same thing later has 26 children (and works fine). 
I've noticed a lot of weird first load issues in react-virtualized usages (like your list not loading initially). Keep in mind that if you're giving react-virtualized data you expect it to update on, make sure that data is changing a prop somewhere. Otherwise nothing inside will re-render.